# How to make this R data.table code more memory-efficient?

Tags: r, data.table

I've got two real-life examples of `data.table` code that work but seem to consume more memory than I'd expect and I'd really appreciate ideas on how to make this  code more memory-efficient.

```
A = data.table(a=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)), b1=2:11, b2=22:31, c=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2))

# Example 1:
# Pick the column name (b1 or b2) based on the value in column a 
# and assign the value from <b1 or b2> by reference to column res
setkey(A, a, c)
A[, res:=get(paste0("b", a)), by=c("a", "c")] 

# Example 2:
# Group the values of A by key, saving the following: 
# 1) number of values in column res that meet some condition
# 2) the minimum value of column a
setkey(A, c)
z = A[, list(length(.I[res>5]), min(res)), by=c]
```

I tested them with much bigger real-life data using `lineprof` and they are outliers in otherwise quite efficient code using `data.tables` throughout.

```
# This is more like the real size of the data I'm dealing with
A = data.table(a=c(rep(1,5e6),rep(2,5e6)), 
               b1=1:5e6, b2=(5e6+1):10e6, 
               c=round(runif(1e7, min=1, max=2)))
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the edit @David - well spotted!

Comment: Does Example one use `by a,c` to process by row? that is what is taking so long

Comment: In my real data, it's not exactly by row - rather, by small groups. Time isn't an issue here - it's actually pretty fast. I'm concerned with the amount of memory it's using.

Comment: I think for second question you could just do `A[, .(sum(res>5), min(res)), by=c]`

Comment: Yup, this makes things faster (although the memory footprint is similar), thanks!

Comment: You also shouldn't call paste in each iteration, you can call it once using `do.call` and then iterate only on `get`, for example `A[, temp := do.call(paste0, list("b", a))][, res := get(temp), .(a, c)]` Though mnel binary search will be much more efficient.

Comment: Bravo, this seems to have saved 50% memory!

Comment: Wasn't @mnels binary join was far more efficient though? I don't get it.

Comment: What's your `data.table` version? Some unwanted leaks (from 1.9.2/1.9.4) were fixed in current devel `1.9.5`.

Comment: It's indeed 1.9.4. Good to know - hopefully the fixes will make it to a stable release soon!

Comment: @msp in your first example you don't need to have `c` in the `by`

Answer (score 2):

If example 1 is simply using `by = list(a,c)` to process by row so get works, then

```
setkey(A,a)
A[.(1), res := b1]
A[.(2), res:= b2]
```

Should be much more efficient

For example 2, ordering / keying by res as well could improve performance

```
setkey(A, c,res)
z = A[, list(length(.I[res>5]),(res[1])), by=c]
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried doing as you suggest in the first example, and it took absolute ages (I've got 75 levels of a in real life). Will try out the second example now!

Comment: Do you've 75 `b` cols? If so, how long does: `A[.(a=1:75), res := get(paste0("b", i.a)), by=.EACHI]` take?

Comment: The i.a syntax is documented in the news. The i.a Component indicates you want to get 'a' from the i argument not the scope of j. (@arun suggestion is brilliant)

Comment: I wrote a happy reply, but then noticed that in my case this example fails to iterate over the levels of `a` for some reason...